# How to represent two teams

Tags: symbols, type, representation, team

I'm making some UI mock-ups for a tournament system. The scenario is that two players are being matched and then compete against each other. Colors is not an option because the system is going to implement in an existing system that already uses colors, and these colors may not always be the same.

The first idea I have is to use symbols.

EDIT: Note that the game/table it self is physical. Only the matching of players and the seating arrangement is done in software.

[image: mockup]

Comment: I don't get the sentence: `But I think it makes a feel of unbalance (no symbols/seat is better than the other)`. Also why does it matter where the players sit? Is it an asymmetric game? What's wrong with Player 1 / Player 2?

Comment: @Larivact I just removed the line, because I can't explain it well enough. But I think that people would have more emotions towards symbols than colors in this context. It does not matter where they play from, but it is a requirement that the players are randomly seated so that they can't pick a side themselves.

Comment: You could just statically number the seats (so that there is seat 1 and seat 2) and then let one player press a button which randomly outputs either 1 or 2 (his seat).

Comment: @Larivact Good idea. I'm trying to make a mockup with that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Symbols won't be **scalable**.

Depending on the amount of Players joining this tournament, you can have **Usernames** or **Number Codes**.

For example, if you have 100 players joining this tournament, you could assign number codes from **0-99** or have them decide their own Username.

How this will matter?

As you said this is a tournament, if you happen to get more number of entries, there are only a limited number of symbols, you will be able to actually assign to every user, unless everyone is assigned one only for the gameplay.

Symbols are harder to identify than Usernames since Usernames are User-defined and hence easily identifiable.

Comment: It is not a software game - only the match/seating arragement is on an software interface. The game/table is physical. There will be stickers on the table that will identify the seat.

Comment: Got it. With Stickers, shapes/ symbols make sense.